# Invalid filter: 'batch'

Tags: django, bat, jinja2, django-filter

В проекте Django в шаблоне используется ряд переменных передаваемых из views.py в шаблон.

Задача: выводить отзывы блоками по 4.
Стандартная реализация, все как по документации.

```
{% for feedbacks_batched in feedbacks|batch(4) %}
  {% for feedback in feedbacks_batched %}
     .....
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

При выполнении получаю ошибку:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/
Django Version: 4.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Invalid filter: 'batch'
```

Не пойму почему? фильтр вроде стандартный встроенный, а не самописный. Или как-то его надо подгружать дополнительно? В чем проблема?